# Jquery and ajax on button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this submit button without a form..

```
<input type='submit' id='conx' name='X' value='TEST x'>
```

Now when the button is clicked i need to execute this code.

```
$con = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "w");
fwrite($con, "XcOn");
close($con);
```

How can i execute it in jquery and ajax?.

```
$("#conx").click(function(){

//Execute this code
//$con = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "w");
//fwrite($con, "XcOn");
//close($con);

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in one file.

### test.php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['cmd'] === 'ajax') {
    $con = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "w");
    fwrite($con, "XcOn");
    fclose($con);
    exit;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>meh</title>
</head>
<body>


<input type="submit" id="conx" name="X" value="TEST x">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#conx").bind('click', function(){
        $.post("test.php", { cmd: "ajax" } );
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot great answer. What if i have 3 button?.. can i just add it on the top?.. e.g. name of button is X,Y and Z

Comment: That would be an easy edit. And it can be done in a number of ways. You could add a new jquery `bind()` for each button with the `$.post` parts `cmd` having different value for each button. Then you would change the php if to include the other cases. Something like this: http://codepad.org/F4RGDJUo

Answer (score 1):

Post that to a PHP page with Ajax and execute those ther

```
$("#conx").click(function(){
  $.post("yourPHPPageWithMagicCode.php");
});
```

Make sure yo have that PHP code in `yourPHPPageWithMagicCode.php` file.

If you want to show a response after the process is done, you can return something from your PHP page and let the callback of $.post handle it.

In your PHP page after your code,put an echo

```
echo "successfully finised";
```

Now change the jquery code to handle the callback

```
$("#conx").click(function(){
  $.post("yourPHPPageWithMagicCode.php",function(repsonse){
    alert(response);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your PHP file is called `write.php`. I believe you can do this:

```
  $("#conx").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/write.php"
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like below inside your click function to call a PHP script:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "URL/TO/PHP/SCRIPT",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: why not use jQuery when available?

Comment: Is there any other way. E.g not creating a extra php file?

Answer (score 0):

You need a jquery ajax call between the click event block

```
$("#conx").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "phpfile.php",
        type: "post",
        //data: serializedData,
        // callback handler that will be called on success
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // log a message to the console
           alert(response);
        }
    });

});
```

put whatever code you want in the phpfile.php file.

Comment: Can it be done without doing this or any other way?.Rather than creating another php file? thanks

Comment: No, this is the only way to do PHP work in javascript events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the 'click event' on the document load i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
     $("#conx").click(function(){ .....
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is

```
$("#conx").click(function(){
    $.post("PHPFILENAME.PHP",{
        whatdo:otherstuff
    },function(d){
        // return d here
    }
})
```

run your code in the php file.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a javascript function from the button:

```
<input type='submit' onclick="myFunction()" id='conx' name='X' value='TEST x'>
```

and have a page load in your function:

```
function myFunction(){
    var loadUrl = "magic.php";  
    var result = $("#result").load(loadUrl);  
}
```

Then have magic.php run your method:

```
//Execute this code
//$con = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "w");
//fwrite($con, "XcOn");
//close($con);
```

This is all untested pseudo-code...

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to not create another php file?.. I need something that will not read another php file. eg execute everything in the current php file.

Comment: You have to make another request to the webserver to do any work, but you could access the existing php page.

You could have a querystring that causes the same file to do a different activity. Something like test.php?logevent=1, then have a simple if statement at the top of test.php that looks for logevent and does your special code instead of its normal activity